# Select record conditionally by comparing date and time

Tags: sqlite, date, select, sql-order-by

Using SQLite, how do I retrieve the first record where current time is between record start and stop times, OR ELSE, if current time is outside start/stop times of all existing records, instead retrieve the record that comes next in time after current local time?

Here's my table:

```
TABLE sessions (
    session_id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    session_start REAL,
    session_stop  REAL,
    group_id      INTEGER REFERENCES [groups] (group_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Example data:

```
session_id  session_start       session_stop        group_id
1           2459599.755438762   2459599.963772095   1
2           2459600.0471054283  2459600.1721054283  2
3           2459600.755438762   2459600.963772095   1
```

The session table has a foreign key, group_id, but for sake of the example maybe we can leave it aside.

EDIT:

Tried mankowitz suggestion within a small test application:

```
SQL.Text:='SELECT *, julianday(''Now'',''localtime'') AS julian_now FROM sessions '
+'WHERE session_start > julian_now '
+'ORDER BY session_stop < julian_now LIMIT 1';
```

Current time at runtime was 2022-01-17 05:40:45 and the record with session_id 16 should have been selected since it is the closest to in time. How to modify the code for this?

[image: Result of SELECT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the condition:

> current time is between record start and stop times

you need this boolean expression in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
julianday('now', 'localtime') BETWEEN session_start AND session_stop
```

and for the condition:

> OR ELSE, if current time is outside start/stop times of all existing
> records, instead retrieve the record that comes next in time after
> current local time

you need this:

```
julianday('now', 'localtime') > session_stop
```

Write your query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sessions 
ORDER BY julianday('now', 'localtime') BETWEEN session_start AND session_stop DESC,
         julianday('now', 'localtime') > session_stop DESC,
         session_start  
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It seems to work fine. I'll do some more tests during the day before accepting the answer. Could you explain why DESC is used? I thought the dates needed to be sorted with the smallest values first?

Comment: Tested it some more and its smooth as glass! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Rimfirea boolean expression like `julianday('now', 'localtime') BETWEEN session_start AND session_stop` is evaluated as 0 for false or 1 for true. By setting DESC all the 1s will be on top.

Answer (score 0):

select * from sessions where sesson_start>{currenttime}
order by session_end<{currenttime}
limit 1

Comment: Thank you, I have tested your code and edited the question. The wrong record was returned, and I don't understand why?